# Как сохранить переменную из функции?

Tags: javascript

Нужно сохранить переменные `var AI_temp_A3_new_OUTGraph` и `var airflowM2Graph` вне функции.

```
function completeFn({data}) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

    var ready = data.map(function(item) {
        return [moment.utc(item.TimeString, 'DD.MM.YY HH:mm:ss'),parseInt(item.VarValue)]}); 




     var Sravnenie = data.map(function(item) {
        return (item.VarName)}); 


        if (Sravnenie[0] == 'AI_M2_airflow_DB_OUT') {

  var airflowM2Graph = ready;
}
        if (Sravnenie[0] == 'AI_temp_A3_new_OUT') {

  var AI_temp_A3_new_OUTGraph = ready; 
}   
    }
```

Например:

Выполнилась функция один раз - там была переменная `var AI_temp_A3_new_OUTGraph`, сохранилась, выполнилась другой раз, там была -`var airflowM2Graph`- сохранилась.

Делаю так, не работает:

```
function completeFn({data}) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

    var ready = data.map(function(item) {
        return [moment.utc(item.TimeString, 'DD.MM.YY HH:mm:ss'),parseInt(item.VarValue)]}); 


     var Sravnenie = data.map(function(item) {
        return (item.VarName)}); 



    }


  if (Sravnenie[0] == 'AI_M2_airflow_DB_OUT') {

  var airflowM2Graph = ready;
}
        if (Sravnenie[0] == 'AI_temp_A3_new_OUT') {

  var AI_temp_A3_new_OUTGraph = ready; 
}
```

Comment: ну дак и определите их вне функции, или в чем вопрос?

Comment: @teran, вне функции ReferenceError: Sravnenie is not defined

Comment: вы не поняли вам нужно объявить их выше и далее просто меняйте их значения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример о чем говорили я и @teran обе переменные доступны в любой нижележащей функции

```js
let airflowM2Graph = 0;
let AI_temp_A3_new_OUTGraph = 0;

function completeFn() {
  airflowM2Graph++;
  AI_temp_A3_new_OUTGraph++;
  show();
}

function show() {
  console.log({
    airflowM2Graph
  }, {
    AI_temp_A3_new_OUTGraph
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="completeFn(1, 2)">click my</button>
<hr>

<button onclick="show()">show result</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `return` для возвращения переменной из функции. Например так:

```
function foo(){
  let a = 'Some value';
  return a;
}

let b = foo();

console.log(b) // Some value
```

Теперь переменная `b` содержит значение переменной `a`, возвращенное из функции `foo()`.

Либо объявить переменные до функции и потом менять их значение. Это выглядит так:

```
let a;
function foo(){
    a = 'Some value';
}

foo()

console.log(a) // Some value
```